# Harpoons in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Can I have any harpoons in TikZ?

I refer to my previous question on harpoons: ["How to draw protocol interaction"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6389/how-to-draw-protocol-interaction-using-tikzpicture) using `amsmath`.
The closest thing I have found is this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={bent,aspect=.3}]  
    \node[circle,draw] (A) at (.5,.5) {A};   
    \node[circle,draw] (B) at (3,1.5) {B};   
    \draw[->,decorate] (A) -- (B);   
    \draw[->,decorate] (B) -- (A);  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are so called *partial arrow tips* in TikZ. Use for instance `left to`, `right to`, `left hook` or `right hook`. They are desribed in section 23.7 of the pfg 2.10 manual (22.6 in the pgf 2.0 manual).

Inserting this into your example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,draw] (A) at (.5,.5) {A};   
    \node[circle,draw] (B) at (3,1.5) {B};   
    \draw[-left to] (A.north east) -- (B.west);   
    \draw[-left to] (B) -- (A);  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I saw that manual. I need two arrows over each other to show protocol interaction. Can you put two arrow connected to two nodes atop of each other in a way that implies simultaneous exchange of messages?

Comment: @Yasser: I've added an example.