# How do I position pairs of arrows in TikZ to make 'harpoons'?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry

I wish to use left-right 'harpoons' to show a reversible reaction in a kinetic scheme. I can get part of the way, but how can I vertically shift the horizontal arrows so that I have them separated (to give harpoons) rather than overlying each another?

Or is there an altogether better way of doing this?

Using TikZ

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
```

Then

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, column sep=3em]
{A + R & AR & AR* \\};
\path[-left to, font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-1) edge node[above]{$k_{+1}$} (m-1-2);
\path[-left to,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-2) edge node[below] {$k_{-1}$} (m-1-1);
\path[-left to,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-2) edge node[above] {$\alpha$} (m-1-3);
\path[-left to,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-3) edge node[below] {$\beta$} (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Updated:** Thanks to all those that responded with advice - all suggesting routes other than TikZ. These are certainly appropriate in many cases, but the reason I went with TikZ was the desire to generate more complex schemes than simple linear equations (see below). Also, a couple of points, ideally I wanted the harpoons to be a fixed length and the reactants not to be in mathmode (ie roman not italic).

I still have no response directly addressing the generation of harpoons in TikZ.

[image]

The picture above was produced with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}


% define matrix
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, column sep=3em, row sep=2em]
{ & & & AR*\\
A + R & ARb & ARc \\
 & & & AD\\};

 % agonist binding
\path[-left to, font=\scriptsize]
(m-2-1) edge node[above]{$k_{+1}$} (m-2-2);
\path[-left to,font=\scriptsize]
(m-2-2) edge node[below] {$k_{-1}$} (m-2-1);

% cleft closure
\path[-left to,font=\scriptsize]
(m-2-2) edge node[above] {$\beta$} (m-2-3);
\path[-left to,font=\scriptsize]
(m-2-3) edge node[below] {$\alpha$} (m-2-2);

% channel opening
\path[-left to, font=\scriptsize]
(m-2-3) edge node[above, xshift=-6] {$\delta$} (m-1-4);
\path[-left to, font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-4) edge node[below, xshift=6] {$\gamma$} (m-2-3);

% desensitization
\path[-left to, font=\scriptsize]
(m-2-3) edge node[above, xshift=16] {1000 s$^{-1}$} (m-3-4);
\path[-left to, font=\scriptsize]
(m-3-4) edge node[below, xshift=-10] {10 s$^{-1}$} (m-2-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/how-do-i-draw-parallel-arrows-in-commutative-diagrams-with-tikz/7166#7166

Comment: Caramdir - thanks for the pointer. Not certain these approaches are appropriate here but I'll have a look.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/harpoons-in-tikz ?

Comment: Does this help?  [How do we mirror a reversible reaction arrow in chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156472/579)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In answer to my original question (above), I found that using the `transform canvas` command provided the easiest way to generate r`ightleftharpoon`-like arrows using TikZ. Thanks to Caramdir for pointing out this [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/how-do-i-draw-parallel-arrows-in-commutative-diagrams-with-tikz/7166#7166). Below is a simple (somewhat meaningless example) showing both horizontal and angled harpoons.

```
\resizebox{!}{!}{  % picture placed inside a resize box (change to values etc as per desired sizing)

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (A) at (0,0) {A + R};
    \node (B) at (1.7,0) {AR};
    \node (C) at (3,1) {AR*};
    \node (D) at (3,-1) {AD};

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={font= \scriptsize}]

\draw[transform canvas={yshift=0.3ex},-left to] (A) -- node[above]{$k_{+1}$}  (B);
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=-0.3ex},left to-] (A) -- node[below] {$k_{-1}$} (B); 

\draw[transform canvas={yshift=0.2ex, xshift=-0.05ex},-left to] (B) --  node[above, xshift=-5]{$\beta$} (C);
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=-0.32ex, xshift=0.2ex},left to-] (B) --  node[below, xshift=5]{$\alpha$} (C);

\draw[transform canvas={yshift=0.32ex, xshift=0.2ex},-left to] (B) --  node[above, xshift=15]{1000 s$^{-1}$}  (D);
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=-0.2ex, xshift=-0.05ex},left to-] (B) --  node[below, xshift=-10]{10 s$^{-1}$}  (D);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture} 

}
```

This produces:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest using the [chemfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) package for such purposes. It has built-in commands for schemes like these which are highly customizable. What's more it provides several arrow types, one of them being harpoons for an equilibrium reaction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,siunitx}
\setchemfig{compound sep=7em} % (not exactly) the length of the arrows
\begin{document}

\schemestart
  A \+ R
  \arrow{<=>[$k_{+1}$][$k_{-1}$]}
  ARb
  \arrow{<=>[$\alpha$][$\beta$]}
  ARc
  \arrow(ARc--){<=>[$\delta$][$\gamma$]}[35] AR$^*$
  \arrow(@ARc--){<=>[\SI{1000}{\per\second}][\SI{10}{\per\second}]}[-35] AD
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution! Certainly easier to follow code than my hack with `transform canvas`. FYI I get `! siunitx error: "support-outdated"` and `Support package expl3 too old.` but I will look into this...

Comment: That sounds like your TeX system isn't up to date...

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
\[
 A + R \xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{k_{+1}} AR \xrightleftharpoons[\alpha]{\beta} AR*
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

At first, I thought of just using the [stackrel](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/stackrel.pdf) package with the `\rightleftharpoons` symbol as the relation.  The problem is that the `\rightleftharpoons` character is fixed width.  Therefore, I first created a macro for typesetting a variable width right-left harpoon in TikZ:

```
\def\longleftrightharpoon#1{\tikz{
  \draw[-left to,above=0.1em] (0,0) -- (#1,0);
  \draw[-left to,below=0.1em] (#1,0) -- (0,0);
}}
```

The argument to that macro is the width of the harpoons.  Next, I created a macro for drawing your reversible reaction using the stackrel package and our new `\longleftrightharpoon` macro:

```
\def\revreact#1#2{{
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle #1$}
  \setbox1=\hbox{$\displaystyle #2$}
  \dimen9=\wd0
  \ifdim\wd1>\dimen9\dimen9=\wd1\fi 
  \,\stackrel[\box1]{\box0}{\longleftrightharpoon{\the\dimen9}}\,
}}
```

What's going on in there is that I first typeset the numerator and denominator to temporary boxes and then I compare the widths of the boxes to see how wide the harpoon should be.

To reproduce your example, one would simply do:

```
\begin{displaymath}
  A + R \revreact{k_{+1}}{k_{-1}} AR \revreact{\alpha}{\beta} AR*
\end{displaymath}
```

which results in the following:

[image: Screenshot of the output.]

You may have to play with the spacing a bit to get it exactly how you want it.
You may also want to reduce the size of the numerators and denominators by removing the "`\displaystyle`" commands from inside the `\setbox`es.  You can also adjust the whitespace surrounding the reactions by altering the `\,` commands.

Answer (score 1):

In the example below, the code for calculating the arrow positions has been factored out into a macro. The nodes can be placed at arbitrary positions, and the arrows are rotated accordingly, while keeping the distance between them constant.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz,calc}       % note we use both package calc 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows} % and tikzlibrary calc

\newdimen{\myx}
\newdimen{\myy}
\newlength{\myxoff}
\newlength{\myyoff}

\newcommand{\reversiblearrow}[3][1]{ 
    % Arguments: Optional arrow spacing, node name 1, node name 2

    % obtain raw difference vector
    \path ($(#3) - (#2)$);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\myx}{\myy};

    % obtain normalized difference vector
    \pgfpointnormalised{\pgfpoint{\myx}{\myy}};
    \pgfgetlastxy{\myx}{\myy};

    % assign real TeX lengths
    \setlength{\myxoff}{\myy}
    \setlength{\myyoff}{\myx}

    \draw[-left to,transform canvas={xshift=-#1\myxoff,yshift=#1\myyoff}]% 
         (#2) -- (#3);
    \draw[left to-,transform canvas={xshift=#1\myxoff,yshift=-#1\myyoff}]% 
         (#2) -- (#3);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) at (0in,0.25in) {A};
\node (B) at (0.5in,0in) {B};
\node (C) at (0.5in,0.5in) {C};

\reversiblearrow{A}{C}
\reversiblearrow{B}{C}

% an arrow pair with wider distance
\reversiblearrow[2]{A}{B}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]