# How do we mirror a reversible reaction arrow in chemfig

Tags: arrows, chemfig

In Chemfig, the reversible reactions are represented with a double harpoon. The top one goes from the left to the right, the bottom from the right to the left. One can rotate this double arrow. But I could not find a way to mirror it, like  `\leftrighharpoon` in the package `mathrel`. This seems silly, but my reactions diagrams are very big and intricated, so the relative position of forward and reverse matter.

I am sorry if I missed something in the manual or in the previous questions asked on this forum.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to define a new arrow. You can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\makeatletter
    \pgfarrowsdeclare{revhalf}{revhalf}%
    {\CF@arrow@size\dimexpr2.5pt+2.5\pgflinewidth\relax
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{-\CF@arrow@size}\pgfarrowsrightextend{.5\pgflinewidth}}%
    {\CF@arrow@size\dimexpr2.5pt+2.5\pgflinewidth\relax
    \pgfsetdash{}\z@\pgfsetroundjoin\pgfsetroundcap
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint\z@\z@}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\CF@arrow@size}{-.5\CF@arrow@size}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.5\CF@arrow@size}\z@}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint\z@\z@}%
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke}

\definearrow3{<==>}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{%
        \noexpand\path[allow upside down](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)%
            node[pos=0,sloped,yshift=1pt](\CF@arrow@start@node @u0){}%
            node[pos=0,sloped,yshift=-1pt](\CF@arrow@start@node @d0){}%
            node[pos=1,sloped,yshift=1pt](\CF@arrow@start@node @u1){}%
            node[pos=1,sloped,yshift=-1pt](\CF@arrow@start@node @d1){};%
        }%
    \CF@tmp@str
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,revhalf-](\CF@arrow@start@node @u0)--(\CF@arrow@start@node @u1);%
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-revhalf](\CF@arrow@start@node @d0)--(\CF@arrow@start@node @d1);%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}+\CF@arrow@start@node{#2}{0.5}-\CF@arrow@end@node%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Normal:

\schemestart
\chemfig{A}
\arrow{<=>}[45]
\chemfig{B}
\arrow{<=>}
\chemfig{C}
\schemestop

Reversed:

\schemestart
\chemfig{A}
\arrow{<==>}[45]
\chemfig{B}
\arrow{<==>}
\chemfig{C}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

I know it can be probably done better and easier, but it should do the work.