# Partial triangular arrows with TikZ/PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'd like to draw a partial arrow (i.e. with only "half" of the tip) but with a triangular tip shape (e.g. using >=latex), instead of the standard single line you get with "left to", "right to", etc.

The result should be something like the following image:

[image: Triangular partial arrow]

How can I achieve this? I haven't seen any such tip in the TikZ/PGF manual.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Harpoons in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/harpoons-in-tikz)

Comment: @Jubobs: I don't think this is a duplicate. Indeed, Didac asked for _triangular tip shapes_ and if I'm not wrong, at the moment they are missing.

Comment: I haven't found any that matched, but your search might be improved by knowing that the symbol to which you refer is often called a "harpoon" rather than a "partial triangular arrow".

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Fair enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The new *really cool* CVS arrow stuff (bendy arrows!) written by Till Tantau  makes all sorts of customization of arrows possible. In particular `left` and `right` parts of arrows can be specified like this `-{Stealth[left]}`

This example is culled from the latest CVS manual:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
\long\def\arrowexample#1{%
    \tt#1 &
    \tikz\draw [-{#1}, very thick](0,0) -- (1,0);
    \\
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[]}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[sep] Stealth[]}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[sep] . Stealth[]}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[open]}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[length=6pt,width=4pt]}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[length=6pt,width=4pt,inset=1.5pt]}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[round]}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[slant=.3]}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[left]}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[right]}
    \arrowexample{Stealth[red]}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks super cool! Is there an easy way to install the arrows.meta library (without having to download to full CVS directory and doing manual installation -- I don't want to mess up my current TikZ system.

Comment: @DidacBusquets As I understand it, all the code for arrows has been completely rewritten from scratch and this involves multiple files not just the `arrows.meta` library. Most people find it quite simple to update using the latest CVS though as explained [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz).

Comment: I got it working!

Answer (score 6):

[Luigi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13482/luigi), out TikZ-arrows guru provided in the Italian forum [something very close to this question](http://www.guitex.org/home/it/forum/5-tex-e-latex/89074-risolto-frecce-parziali-tikz#89091) (for stealth tip).

Building on that:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{left stealth}{left stealth}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-3\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+5\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{5\pgfutil@tempdima-\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{6\pgfutil@tempdima}{-0.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{right stealth}{right stealth}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-3\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+5\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{5\pgfutil@tempdima-0.5\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{6\pgfutil@tempdima}{0.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{left triangle}{left triangle}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-3\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+5\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{5\pgfutil@tempdima-\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{5.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{-0.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{right triangle}{right triangle}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-3\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+5\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{5\pgfutil@tempdima-0.5\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{5.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[right stealth-right stealth]   (0,0)--(2,0);
\draw[left stealth-left stealth]     (0,1)--(2,1);
\draw[right triangle-right triangle] (0,2)--(2,2);
\draw[left triangle-left triangle]   (0,3)--(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]